# Angular Datatable: How to get tooltip of column data while hovering

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-datatables

I have one datatable. how to get `tooltip` while hovering on table cells? Tried the below type, the `tooltip` is populating. How to get the same using angular?

```
 $(document).on("mousemove", "tr td", function () {
  var colVal = $(this).text();
 $(this).prop("title", colVal);
});
```

[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-all-current-page?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can achive that pretty easy with implementing bootstrap. something like this should do the trick:

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let person of persons">
    <td data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement = "bottom" title="{{yourTooltip.content}}" >
       <input type="checkbox" [disabled]="person.firstName === 'Superman'"
       class="checkboxCls" [value]="person.checked" [checked]="person.checked"
       name="id" (change)="person.checked = !person.checked">
   </td>
    <td data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement = "bottom" title="{{yourTooltip.content}}">{{ person.id }}</td>
    <td data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement = "bottom" title="{{yourTooltip.content}}">{{ person.firstName }}</td>
    <td data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement = "bottom" title="{{yourTooltip.content}}">{{ person.lastName }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Don't forget to always add `data-container="body"` otherwise the tooltip will move the table cells to the right a bit on hover.